# Shape of a dialog window

Tags: android, shapes

Want to create a dialog activity which open on the click of a floating view,the problem is i am unable to find how to set the shape of dialog, like of facebook chathead a triangle at the top of dialog activity touching the floating view.

Comment: Can u share the image which you want to set as dialog?

Comment: This is the problem i have the image but can't share as my reputation is less than 10.

Comment: @DroidAks http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/04/fb_chatheads_stickers.png

Check this image see the small triangle on the top of dialog, i want to create that on my dialog